# Does it matter how far down the page you place breadcrumbs for SEO?

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

I am wanting to integrate breadcrumbs into a client site. The client is fine with this but wants them at the bottom of the page. Does this have any negative effects on breadcrumbs contribution to SEO improvements?

Google directly displays breadcrumbs under site links via structured data.  I know Google can pick and decide what structured data it will actually display despite the information you provided. So I am wondering if they are too low on the page if they have a less likelihood of showing up under some links. I don't know if breadcrumbs are treated like other structured data in this regard and what effects them.

Comment: I gave up on breadcrumbs a long time ago. Google is funny about showing them in the SERPs. Being low on the page may still work for what you are suggesting. Who knows? Worth an experiment if someone is willing to try. As for users, I still say they should be where people expect them. Why break tradition when we have all been trained already? Like lemmings.

Comment: I agree fully, its silly putting them at the bottom. I will try to convince him otherwise.

Comment: _Aside:_ I'm curious why the client only wants them at the bottom? Is there something obtrusive about them in the proposed design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't matter what the user sees, you can put them wherever you want. If you are adding them to the bottom, I would recommend putting the breadcrumb schema on them so Google will know exactly what they are. I don't think position is that important.

http://schema.org/breadcrumb

Google doesn't say anything specific about the positioning on their description:

> A set of links that can help a user understand and navigate a website hierarchy.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Zach.. That was the logic i came up with as well. As long as the structured data is properly defined than google should find and display with out issue.

Ill also note for any future people reading this, this is of course speculation based on the most common sense answer. Take everything with a grain of salt. Google is not as open as they used to be.